# Flutter - _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am using firebase to create a SignIn-Sign-up page.
But when i run main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AuthService()),
      ],
child:MyApp(
      )));} 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

[image: error]

This is the login page code:

```
child: ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
     if (isLogin) {
       login();
      } else {
       registrar();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Provide more information. Can't understand what's going on looking at your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get null when we dont use `formKey`. make sure to use `key` property on `Form` widget. For this part, I am providing default value false on null case.

```dart
onPressed: () {
    final isValided  =  formKey.currentState?.validate() ??false;
    if (isValided  ) {
     if (isLogin) {
       login();
      } else {
       registrar();
     }
   }
```